# Почему стрелки движения игрового объекта Unity смещены от него?

Tags: unity3d

Как это исправить? Мне это нужно для правильного вращения этого объекта
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если нужно то вот координаты стрелок
x = -7.968692, y = -7.023793, z = -3.285539

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще это из за неправильной модельки, в юнити нет возможности перемещать пивот (пивот это вот эти стрелочки), Можете сделай попроще, создайте пустой объект и поместите вашу модельку в этот пустой объект (сделайте модельку дочерней), после просто переместите подельку +- в центр пустого объекта ии все махинации с физикой колайдерами и т.д. проводите не смоделькой а этим пустым объектом